# SQL job and stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks, ibm-mq

I have a stored procedure which will pick MQ files from receive location, process it and drop it in save location.

Currently, this stored procedure is not working when I execute it manually.

But files are picked up and saved in the save location automatically at a particular time of day daily. I don't know which stored procedure is calling for this.

There is a SQL Server job which is set up daily at this particular time. This job is calling the same stored procedure which i call manually.

When I try to run the SQL job manually the files are not picked up.

Will be there any mechanism in MQ to pick the files and drop it in receive location?

Comment: When you run it manually, does it run as the same user as when it runs automatically?

Comment: yes it run in the same user !

Comment: Can you post the code for the stored procedure?

Comment: Is the code assuming anything about a current working directory, or does it use absolute paths?

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess is: domain access rights. When the procedure is called by SQL Agent, it is being run under the authority (domain access rights) of the account that is "running" the SQL Agent service. This account has the proper access rights to the folders you are accessing.

When you log on and call the procedure, it is being run under your access rights, and you may not have sufficient rights on those targeted folders to do the work listed.

It could be more complex than that. Once you leave the realm of simple database operation and start using SQL to mess about on your network, there's a world of proxy accounts and obscure features that you have to deal with. It can and has been done, but it's rarely simple to configure. A lot depends on how you (well, the code) has been implemented.

Comment: I just noticed the date/time this question was originally posted. Feh.